# Git hook can't change file permission

Tags: git, githooks

I have a post-receive hook that executes a shell script that changes some files' permissions, but this is not happening because I get the error

> chown: changing ownership of 'example': Operation not permitted

Some files show that error, some others just fail silently.

**How can I change file permission in a git hook (especifically a post-receive one)?**

**PS:** Git hook's user is `git` and so is the owner/group of the files I'm trying to change permission. I'm using chown to reinforce owner and change group of those files.

#### Conclusion

I did accept and answer to what I asked initially but I decided not to do that in a git hook but in another script that I execute manually every so often.

Comment: "Operation not permitted" (EPERM) is an OS level error indicating that the user doing the operation has insufficient privileges. In general, "chown" is restricted on Unix-ish systems to the super user. This can't be done directly from a Git hook because the hook is run by an unprivileged user; running it as super-user is unwise for many reasons. If you really need to change file ownership, a safer method is to have a privileged daemon that can do it upon request, where the daemon vets (verifies) the request.

Comment: @torek I guess the same happens for `chmod`?

Comment: chmod is normally permitted (although ACLs can interfere, if your system has ACLs in the first place and if they're of a sufficiently complicated variety in the second) *provided* the user doing the chmod owns the file. If you successfully give the file away, or never owned it in the first place, you can no longer change its mode.

Comment: @torek What is a privileged daemon? I actually changed my mind and want to create one.

Comment: Privileges are anywhere from really simple ("the superuser can do anything and everyone else can do almost nothing", a la Version 6 Unix) to horribly complex (SELinux, or Windows-style ACLs). The answer therefore depends on your OS and, for many modern OSes, every one of up to hundreds of individual settings. There's no single sweeping answer. (If you're running some particular flavor of Linux, there's probably a superuser.stackexchange.com answer for that particular flavor.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact it's not a good idea (as mentioned in comments) you could possibly do this using SUID or SGID bit on a file (the `post-receive` itself or some external one, run from the `post-receive`).

> SUID is defined as giving temporary permissions to a user to run a program/file with the permissions of the file owner rather that the user who runs it.

You can read how to set this bit [here](http://www.linuxnix.com/suid-set-suid-linuxunix/).